# Im having trouble getting python-decouple to work

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-decouple

```
   pip install python-decouple   
   from decouple import config
   
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple'    

  

   print(API_USERNAME=config('first_name'))
```

keep getting this error even after i installed it correctly, and i uninstalled "decoupler" as well. I also tried installing it with conda still the same issue i honestly stuck

```
python --version

3.9.7

python -m pip install decouple
```

Doesnt work

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64 *
 -3.9-64



from decouple import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'decouple' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decouple\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full command that you think installed the `decouple` module, and also show us the import statement that is causing this error.  I know both of these things could be fairly obvious, but it's always better to provide as much detail as possible as to what you are doing.  Even giving the full error with a stack trace might be helpful.

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions installed?  You may be experiencing a very common problem...you may be installing the `decouple` package into one version of Python but then running your code with another.  This is especially easy to do if you are installing packages via the command line or some other package manager, but are then running your code with a separate IDE.   If possible, test this by using the same exact Python binary by doing `python -m pip install decouple` and then `python <yourapp>.py`.

Comment: This didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
virtualenv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
pip install python-decouple
```

Comment: Its in my question that i already tried that..

Comment: Use a virtualenv so it isolate your application from the variant version of system

Comment: im trying to use the script on my system

Comment: If executing these three lines (replacing the second line with `. ./venv/bin/activate` if you aren't on Windows) gives no errors, and then executing `python -c "from decouple import config"` gives you the error you are reporting, then something is screwed up with your system or your Python installation.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using vscode and a virtual environment try to enter ctrl + shift + p and select python intepreter then click on Enter interpreter path now go to you virtual environment file and navigate to scripts go to right click on python.exe select copy path  and past as interpreter path

Comment: This made me crazy. Install, Reinstall, recreate the enviroment. Usually it works fine without set the interpreter. you deserve this answer to be marked as best answer. Thanks